# Ruby gotchas when it comes to class inheritance

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm coming from a static typed language background (C#/Java), and while I have developed apps using Rails, I'm still not fully confident when in comes to class design.

**Are there any 'gotchas' when it comes to inheritance in Ruby?**

Maybe things to do with static variables, constructors (initializers), the meta/singleton class (I think the official name is something like eugene class)?

I have read a ruby book and I'm looking for those with real world experience to point out things that might not be so obvious in practise.

Comment: Can you make your question more specific? Are you having some troubles with class inheritance in Ruby?

Comment: This is not a good question for Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) to understand why. The "Related" questions on the lower right should provide you with many similar questions.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest gotcha I encountered is that "class variables" (variables whose names start with `@@`) don't behave the way you would expect.  The variable is actually shared among the class and all the subclasses, so you can't change its value in the subclasses without affecting the parent class.  Here's an example:

```
class Foo
  @@x = 1

  def self.x
    @@x
  end
end

class Goo < Foo
  @@x = 2
end

puts Foo.x  # => 2
puts Goo.x  # => 2
```

Instead of using class variables, you might want to use *instance variables of the class object*, but then you don't automatically get inheritance so you have to define all those variables each time you define a new subclass:

```
class Moo
  @y = 1

  def self.y
    @y
  end
end

class Noo < Moo
  @y = 2
end

puts Moo.y   # => 1
puts Noo.y   # => 2
```

Alternatively, just make a class method (e.g. `self.x`) that returns the desired value.  Then you get inheritance and the ability to override it in subclasses.

Comment: Thanks, you know that is exactly what I was looking for.  I read this chapter on inheritance a while back, and I recall something to do with class variables that I just didn't understand, and this was it.

Comment: That's the definition of a class variable. There's a gem, and Rails includes an inheritable class variable method to avoid this behavior and the need to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I've discovered as I'm using Ruby more and more is to avoid using inheritance unless it really is *necessary* and logical to do so. So much more can be accomplished in Ruby by using modules and including them in your class than in C#/Java.

Doing so will make your design more flexible and easier to use in any unforeseen scenarios where a consumer of the design doesn't want to "use up" their parent class just to satisfy your library/API. Additionally, this helps me follow the "favor composition over inheritance" wisdom in a new way I couldn't in C#/Java.

Not sure if this qualifies as a 'gotchya' or simply something new to consider compared to those other languages.

Comment: I think it's neat that modules look a lot like classes in ruby.  You can do `obj.is_a?(Rideable)` whether Rideable is a module or a class.  You don't have to know it when you write that code, and Rideable can change from a class to a module without affecting that code.  You can also do `obj.respond_to?(:ride)` to be even more flexible.

Comment: @DavidGrayson You shouldn't need to use `is_a?` very often (if ever), unless as a guard mechanism (not typical in Ruby code).

Comment: @DaveNewton. What do you use instead?  I can think of 3 things: respond_to?, ===, and case.  I think the latter two are just as objectionable as is_a?, but I'm not sure why you object.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I use tests. As I said, unless you're specifically writing guard clauses, OOP code should essentially never need to have manual branches based on type--it defeats the purpose.